# Web based or windows based gRPC Client

Tags: javascript, java, php, .net, grpc

We are working on gRPC Services on the .Net project. Tried to use gRPC on Postman but did not get success.

Does anyone know web-based or windows based gRPC clients?

Comment: [bloomrpc](https://github.com/uw-labs/bloomrpc) works well for me (but the question is off topic).

Comment: I think you can take a look into [Kreya](https://kreya.app/).

Answer (score 0):

Try https://github.com/fullstorydev/grpcui (which is based on [gRPCurl](https://github.com/fullstorydev/grpcurl))